# How to import Net Framework classes as sourse files to use at project?

Tags: haxe

From here https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/HaxeManual/wiki/Haxe-C%23 I've learned:

> Haxe can directly load .NET assembly files (.DLL) and convert its type definitions for use as Haxe types. To load a .NET assembly, use -net-lib library.dll compiler option. Haxe will then automatically parse types defined in that assembly file and make them available for import as Haxe types.

Fine, I want import Forms.DLL. Not `haxe -net-lib C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll` nor `haxelib -net-lib C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll` made something.

Then I've found that https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/DS8AXeWxiTA . Guy here uses

> haxe  -cp src -cs F:/_dev/CSTest2/CSTest2 -D net-ver=40 -D net-std=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ -main Main -net-lib Accessibility.dll@std -net-lib System.Drawing.dll@std -net-lib System.Windows.Forms.dll@std

I suppose its compile.hxml file setting. But... Its **compile** file. I still getting error of unknown "*import cs.system.windows.forms.Form;*". So its like should already exist at my source files before compilation starts.

Here is my current *compile.hxml* which I've tried to compile:

```
-main Main
-cp src
-cs bin
-D net-ver=40
-D -net-std=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
-net-lib C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Accessibility.dll@std 
-net-lib C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll@std
-net-lib C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Drawing.dll@std
```

And got huge amount of errors similar to that example:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll @ cs.system.windows.forms.ImageList (Finalize):1: character 0 : Invalid override on field 'Finalize': class has no super class
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll @ cs.system.windows.forms.ImageList:1: character 0 : Defined in this class

So where is I'm wrong. Or what should I add/edit to start using Net Framework at haxe project?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what it is you're doing... But it looks like that error has to do with windows form library. What happens when you take out the windows form definition?  Is it referencing the right library?

Comment: I'm simply trying build empty project with `import cs.system.windows.forms.Form;` in it. If I remove that import then `Build succeeded` (with the same as above compile.hxml file). And the main question how to add Net Framework classes to project as haxe not provide tools for that? Also using Form via Visual Studio works fine

Comment: Also haxe project IDE is Haxe Develop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finalizer errors you're getting are a known issue with `-net-lib`, see [#5241](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/5241). Fortunately, there's been a fix in October which is included in [Haxe 4.0.0-preview.2](https://haxe.org/download/version/4.0.0-preview.2/). The fix is *not* included in the latest stable release (3.4.4).

Comment: I've downloaded and installed haxe from haxe_latest.zip. And yes, error disappeared. But now I'm getting error `Type not found : cs.system.windows.forms.Form`. And I can actualy understand this. Cuz type realy doesn't exist at my source path. And all info I could find is about compilation parameters. Not how to "convert its type definitions for use as Haxe types" nor how to at least add autocompletion. Also I've reinstalled hxcs but it still shows version "3.4.0". Couldn't it be a problem?

Comment: Hm, strange... using your compilation parameters, I can compile + run [this](https://gist.github.com/Gama11/f5880a3dc1e9e5cda4823fccd2a56bcf) without any issues. And yes, the latest version of hxcs is indeed 3.4.0, that shouldn't be a problem. Auto-completion also works fine for me (using VScode, but it should also work in HaxeDevelop).

Comment: Even copied your example. Still same error. Just wanna understand how it should works when no errors. Am I right that using compile parameter `-net-lib somelibrary.dll` haxe creates *someNetFrameworkClass.hx* classes at your project source path. Which is leads to autocomletion and futher safe compilation (I mean you should run it first time for completly empty project cuz Form.hx not exist at "source" before first run)?

Comment: How are you compiling exactly, `haxe build.hxml`? And no, there are no `.hx` files created for .NET classes. Haxe loads the type definitions directly from the DLL (for e.g. auto-completion).

Comment: sorry, for late respond. I've used pre-build command line and `$(CompilerPath)\haxe.exe $(ProjectDir)\compile.hxml` to compile. I'm speaking about [that](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/DS8AXeWxiTA) example. This way works fine for non Net Framework included compile. After your post I've decided to create compile.bat with "haxe (path)\compile.hxml" and suddenly it passed. App works fine. But it strange that native Haxe Develop cant operate Net Framework libraries smooth by default. I forced to use "Custom build". Also I didn'f find way to simply attach NF classes to project.

Comment: Cant use hotkey "import" class and forced to manualy write each import or write full path each time class mentioned. I'm even thinking of creating sub classes of Net Fr-k which simply call super class methods and do nothing more. Only to camforable use it... Thanks for info though =)

Comment: Have you tried using the hxml project type? https://i.imgur.com/GbZFIPj.png Not surprised completion isn't working properly if you're using a pre-build command like that - HD won't know the correct compiler arguments to use for completion.

Comment: Chosen `hxml` as Platform and `compile.hxml` as Conf file. But nothing seems changed (except more simplier compilation without errors). I still able to use package autocomplition as at "C#" Paltform target (like write *cs.system.windows.forms.Button* and will get completion on each dot, but no import will be added and next use of **Button** I should write whole path again). Looks like *Haxe Develop* not use path to *Net Framework* and packages from `compile.hxml`. And I not see **NF** classes on global classes list (Ctrl+Alt+Space). So **HD** only check `hxml` while compiling.

Comment: Also listed above is right for "Compilation target" -> "Custom build". If "Application" chosen instead then there happens a lot of errors during compilation like: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll @ cs.system.windows.forms.IContainerControl (get_ActiveControl):1: character 1 : This platform does not support this kind of overload declaration. Try @:overload(function()... {}) instead
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll @ cs.system.windows.forms.IContainerControl:1: character 1 : Defined in this class` And no completion too